# Restore Firefox icon removed by mistake from the screen

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, home-screen, app-icons

I don't know how I did removed the firefox app icon from the main scren

How can I restore it?

My phone is using Android 5.1 and it is a TPLink Neffos C5

Edit:
The icon is not present in the app drawer

[image]

But at the applications section

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As unusual, my phone does not support app drawer, but it comes with a feature named **Hidden apps**, the solution was:

1. Access **hidden apps** by doing a 2-finger swipe on the home screen.
2. Search for the firefox icon and add it to the **hidden apps**.
3. Close and reopen **hidden apps**.
4. Press edit and unselect the icon.

Now it should appear at the end of your screens.